# If $P(A) = P(B) = p$, then $P(AB) \leq p^2$?

Tags: probability

Is this true or false?
I guess if I can find a counter-example where $P(AB) > p^2$, I can say that it's false, but I can't think of any.

Comment: By $AB$ do you mean $A$ and $B$? If so, what about when $A=B$?

Comment: Yes, by $AB$, I mean $A$ and (intersection) $B$. If $A = B$, then wouldn't we have $P(AB) = P(A) = P(B) = p < p^2$?

Comment: If $p$ is less than $1$ then $p^2 \leq p$

Comment: Oh right, it's between 0 and 1...Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway if $A$ and $B$ are events the probability measure of $A \cap B$ can be anywhere between $min\{P(A), P(B)\}$ and $0$. The maximum is attained when $A \subset B$ and the minimum is attained when $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Comment: I can't upvote you due to lack of reputation, but I appreciate the clarification, thanks.

Comment: @shona But you can accept the answer of Lee Fisher.